# Django Integrity Error - NOT NULL constraint failed: zdorovo_page.category_id

Tags: django, django-forms

While working with Django, I created an app which shows different categories. Click on any one of them it opens up a window showing all the pages related to it . On the same window you have the option to add a new page to that particular category.
I am getting this integrity error type for a value of not null constraint failed error. I cannot comprehend this error. Please help me understand where am i going wrong . I have posted all the required scripts.

```
models.py
from django.db import models
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify

class Category(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
     slug = models.SlugField(blank = True, null= True)

     def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
         self.slug = slugify(self.name)
         super(Category, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

     class Meta:
         verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

     def __unicode__(self):
         return self.name

class Page(models.Model):
     category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
     title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
     url = models.URLField()
     views = models.IntegerField(default=0)

     def __unicode__(self):
         return self.title
```

I am basically trying to add a page to an existing category. This is my add_page view

```
views.py for add_page
def add_page(request , category_name_slug):
    category = Category.objects.get(slug = category_name_slug)
    form = PageForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PageForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            if category:
                page = form.save(commit = True)
                page.category = category
                page.views = 0
                page.save()
                return about(request , category_name_slug)
        else:
            print form.errors
    return render(request , 'zdorovo/add_page.html' , {'form': form , 'category': category})
```

**about** here is a view that takes care of the existing pages to a particular category and displays them.

This is my forms.py

```
class CategoryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=128, help_text="Please enter the category name.")
    views = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial=0)
    likes = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial=0)
    slug = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), required=False)


    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ['name',]

class PageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=128, help_text="Please enter the title of the page.")
    url = forms.URLField(max_length=200, help_text="Please enter the URL of the page.")
    views = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial=0)

    class Meta:
        model = Page
        exclude = ('category',)
```

Please update me if anyone requires anything from my side.

P.S.- All indentation have been taken care of , no error from that end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Page model category is a required field. But when you do `page = form.save(commit = True)` it is trying to save page object without any category assigned. Hence you are getting the Integrity Error.

Try

```
def add_page(request , category_name_slug):
    category = Category.objects.get(slug = category_name_slug)
    form = PageForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PageForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            if category: 
                page = form.save(commit = False) # tells Django that "Don't send this to database yet.
                # I have more things I want to do with it.
                page.category = category
                page.views = 0
                page.save()
                return about(request , category_name_slug)
        else:
            print form.errors
    return render(request , 'zdorovo/add_page.html' , {'form': form , 'category': category})
```

Comment: Did that and got the result.

Answer (score 0):

you are so close. Change:

```
page = form.save(commit=True)
```

to

```
page = form.save(commit=False)
```

this way the Form's object won't be saved to the database when the form is converted to the model object. It will be saved after you manually set the `category`.

Hope this helps.